# Need help removing elements from a TXT Import file that has now changed that is brought into SQL Using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

We have a small .net vb application that reads a text file that's created by our clocking in machines.

This information is then stored into a SQL Database.

The data lines used to look like this (below)

5208,05/06/2013,06:27:18,1

This was an ID, Date, Time and Clockin Value.

The code to split the text up and get it ready for the sql is show below:

```
            For Each fileInfo As FileInfo In allFiles
                If fileInfo.Length > 0 Then
                    If fileInfo.LastWriteTime <> Now Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                        Dim srReader As New StreamReader(fileInfo.FullName.ToString)
                        strSplit = Split(srReader.ReadToEnd(), Chr(13))
                        srReader.Close()
                        srReader.Dispose()
                        srReader = Nothing
                        For intInner As Integer = 0 To strSplit.Length - 1
                            strInnerSplit = Split(strSplit(intInner), ",")
                            If strInnerSplit.Length > 3 Then
                                Dim strCard As Integer = strInnerSplit(0)
                                Dim intType As Integer = strInnerSplit(3)
                                Dim dteInOut As Date = strInnerSplit(2)
                                Dim dteDate As Date = strInnerSplit(1)

                                If alreadyInsertedWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType) = False Then
                                    importWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

We now have an issue as the clocking machines format has change to include some extra information at he front of the file that we don't need.

Office         %5197,04/06/2013,22:08:54,2

The First element up to and including the % is fixed width, and always has the %.

Is there an easy what to drop this in the code, so that we just capture the 5197,04/06/2013,22:08:54,2 for example, or is it a rewrite, as I am not a developer, just inherited the issue.

cheers

John

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
                    For intInner As Integer = 0 To strSplit.Length - 1
                        strInnerSplit = Split(strSplit(intInner), ",")
                        If strInnerSplit.Length > 3 Then
                            'Use the split method on the % and use the second
                            'element which is index 1
                            Dim strCard As Integer = strInnerSplit(0).Split("%")(1)
                            Dim intType As Integer = strInnerSplit(3)
                            Dim dteInOut As Date = strInnerSplit(2)
                            Dim dteDate As Date = strInnerSplit(1)

                            If alreadyInsertedWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType) = False Then
                                importWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this ...

Declare string var .. `Dim s as String`

```
                        For intInner As Integer = 0 To strSplit.Length - 1
                            s=Split(strSplit(intInner), "%")(1)
                            strInnerSplit = Split(s, ",")
                            If strInnerSplit.Length > 3 Then
                                Dim strCard As Integer = strInnerSplit(0)
                                Dim intType As Integer = strInnerSplit(3)
                                Dim dteInOut As Date = strInnerSplit(2)
                                Dim dteDate As Date = strInnerSplit(1)

                                If alreadyInsertedWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType) = False Then
                                    importWithinSQL(strCard, dteDate & " " & dteInOut, intType)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
```